# XAMPP pointing a file outside root folder

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, localhost, xampp, documentroot

I am using XAMPP for first time in Mac. Running out problems accessing other than root folder(htdocs).when I am placing my web application inside htdocs with default httpd.conf file it works when I try to point my web application url in httpd.conf it throws error

I am aware that to modify the root folder I need to do changes to my XAMPP/etc/httpd.conf file

With Default XAMPP MAC Settings, I am trying to change Server root,Document root and Directory in XAMPP/etc/httpd.conf file the following

```
ServerRoot "/Users/ravi/Documents/Development/Backbone/backboneboilerplate"

DocumentRoot "/Users/ravi/Documents/Development/Backbone/backboneboilerplate"

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>

<Directory "/Users/ravi/Documents/Development/Backbone/backboneboilerplate">

Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
Allow from all

</Directory>
```

its throwing error when trying to start XAMPP

> httpd: Syntax error on line 54 of
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/httpd.conf: Cannot load
>   /Users/ravi/Documents/Development/Backbone/backboneboilerplate/modules/mod_authn_file.so
>   into server: cannot create object file image or add library

Answer (score 1):

> ServerRoot "/Users/ravi/Documents/Development/Backbone/backboneboilerplate"

Shouldn't be changed - this should point to the Apache install folder; as per: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#serverroot

> The ServerRoot directive sets the directory in which the server lives.
>   Typically it will contain the subdirectories conf/ and logs/. Relative
>   paths in other configuration directives (such as Include or
>   LoadModule, for example) are taken as relative to this directory.

Comment: I tried pointing the XAMPP root folder to Server root but it gives me the forbidden error.

Forbidden
You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Comment: That's probably still incorrect, I don't know where XAMPP is installed on your system, but I'd try pointing it to the directory where the httpd.conf file is.

Answer (score 0):

It was a `chmod` problem. I tried `chmod -r 777` on the Development folder, backbone folder and Backboneboilerplate.. It worked.